# Drive Folder in AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to create a folder in Users or Team Drive and add files to that folder (with drive picker).

Any of you have already executed this?

My use case:

Create a Driver with a driver license number
when adding this item to DB: create a fodler in user/Team drive with license number
next screen is to user upload files to that folder.

Is this possible?

Tried to use this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#addFolder(Folder)

But not even can add this script to my application

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrivePicker widget provides you various events via which you need to handle this use case. I would suggest you to use `onDocumentSelect` event in which you can call your method. In the method you can make a server method call. In the server method use `DriveApp` API to create folder, files etc. Hope this helps.